# find value integral $\int_{1}^{2}f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

For a function $f(x)$ determined and continuous with $\forall x\in $ $\Bbb R\setminus\left\{ 0 \right\}$  such that

$$x^{2}f^{2}(x)+(2x-1)f(x)=xf'(x)-1$$ and $f(1)=-2$

Find 
$$\int_{1}^{2} f(x)dx $$

I write: 
$$(xf(x)+1)^{2}=(xf(x)+1)'$$

But I do not know how to proceed

Comment: Maybe you could define $g(x) := x f(x) +1$ and solve the differential equation: $g^2 - g' = 0$

Comment: oh i don't know solve the equation $g^2-g'=0$

Comment: This is a differential equation with separable variable:
$g^2 -g' = 0 \Leftrightarrow$ $\frac{1}{g^2} g' = 1$ (assuming $g^2 \neq 0$), you should be able to integrate both sides now and extract $g(x)$.

Comment: ok . thamk you ,i did understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from the comments, you can rewrite $g(x) = xf(x)+1$. Then

$$ g(1) = 1\cdot f(1) + 1 = -1 $$

The equation becomes

$$ \frac{g'(x)}{(g(x))^2} = 1 $$

Then
$$ \left[-\frac{1}{g(x)}\right]' = 1 $$

Integrating both sides

$$ -\frac{1}{g(x)} = x + C $$

Using the initial condition as above, we have
$$ -\frac{1}{g(1)} = 1 + C \implies 1 + C = 1 \implies C = 0 $$

Solving for $g(x)$

$$ g(x) = -\frac{1}{x} $$

Solving for $f(x)$

$$ f(x) = \frac{g(x)-1}{x} = -\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x} $$

You can now do the integration

Answer (score 1):

The easiest course of action seems to be to solve the ODE $(xf(x)+1)^{2}=(xf(x)+1)'$ rather than trying to use this property to compute the integral in some clever way.
If we write $g(x)=xf(x)+1$, the ODE becomes $g(x)^2=g'(x)$ with $g(1)=-1$.

As noted in the comments, this is a separable ODE.
The general solution is $g(x)=(C-x)^{-1}$ (where defined), and with $g(1)=-1$ we get $g(x)=-1/x$.
I am leaving the details out; it is a good exercise to solve this, and you can always ask a follow-up question for help if you get stuck.

We thus found that $xf(x)+1=-1/x$, so that $f(x)=-x^{-1}-x^{-2}$.
The integral is now straightforward to calculate.

Comment: Why g(x)=$(C-x)^-1$ what ODE?

Comment: @HaismitnguyenNguyen The abbreviation ODE stands for "Ordinary Differential Equation". If you follow the steps of solving a separable ODE, you get the formula I mentioned. I suggest reading on separable differential equations if you haven't yet. Dylan's answer gives the same formula, albeit not directly. (And to be pedantic, you need to worry about the points where $g(x)=0$ or $g$ blows up, but there are no real difficulties in that respect here.)

Comment: Can you explain why $ g(x)=(C-x)^{-1}$ by ODE?

Comment: @HaismitnguyenNguyen That is done in Dylan's answer. I left it out, as it is something that would be good for you to do by hand. If you want more details on that, please try to do it yourself (look up separable differential equations) and ask a follow-up question if necessary.